# Considering equivalence relations and the compositions of relations

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I have two relations:

$$\begin{align}
A &= \{(x,y), (y,z), (z,x)\} \\
B &= \{(y,x), (z,y), (x,z)\}
\end{align}$$

Both on $\{x,y,z\}$.

I know neither relation is an equivalence relation as they don't exhibit reflexivity, transitivity, or symmetry. $A \cup B$ shows transitivity and reflexivity, but not symmetry.

I want to find $A \circ B$: what does this look like, and what are its equivalence classes? I'm not familiar with this symbol but I am with cross product ($\times$), is it related?

Comment: The notion you want is called [composition of relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations) .

Comment: Are you familiar with composition of functions?

Comment: @Y.Forman sure. Is the concept the same? ie. $A(x) = y$, $(B\circ A)(x) = A(B(x)) = A(z) = x$?

Comment: @gator Yup. Relations are more general than functions, so the concept has to be generalized a bit (though your relations $A$ and $B$ actually are functions).

Comment: @Y.Forman ah, so $B \circ A = \{(x, x), (y, y), (z, z)\}$? Just to confirm the exercise.

Comment: @gator Exactly.